# Is "to collaborating" correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I am interested in this sentence: "I am used to collaborating with other people".
I am not sure if this form is correct, maybe "I am used to collaborate with other people" is more correct?

Comment: The "to" belongs to "used to" and is unrelated to "collaborating", per se. That said, the word following "used to" is typically a gerund (-ing word), so "I'm used to collaborating..." is both normal usage and correct grammar. For that reason, your alternative "I am used to collaborate..." doesn't follow the rules of English grammar, and would sound foreign and awkward to a native speaker.

Comment: ... But, to confuse matters, **used** + *infinitive* is an idiomatic form that (approximately) means the past tense of the verb. So, it would be correct to say, "I used to collaborate with other people, but now I work on my own."

Comment: I concur with what others have said regarding 'used to'. But take care with the use of 'collaborating'. Whilst it does have a business use, when talking about companies working together, or even individuals, it is a word which is often associated with 'collaborating with the enemy'. In war a 'collaborator' is typically a resident of an occupied country who collaborates with the occupying forces. So the word does have unfortunate associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, *used to* is an adjective form.

> made familiar with; accustomed to: *I am used to hitchhiking* [*[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/used-to)*]

Because it includes a preposition, the phrase takes an object, usually a noun form. *Collaborating* is the gerund, a noun form of the verb *collaborate*.

The sentence is correct as is. The alternative *I am used to collaborate ...* is not.

However, *I used to collaborate* would be correct. In this case, *used* is a verb form that means

> (takes an infinitive or implied infinitive) used as an auxiliary to express habitual or accustomed actions, states, etc, taking place in the past but not continuing into the present: *I don't drink these days, but I used to, I used to fish here every day* [*[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/used-to)*]

Note that these sentences mean different things. The first means *I am accustomed to collaborating* and perhaps even *I am inured to collaborating*. The latter means *In the past I have collaborated*. Whether I ever got used to it is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The *to* in *BE used to*, meaning "BE accustomed to" or "familiar with" is an ordinary preposition, taking a nominal object:

> He was a strong lad, used to hardships.
>   We're used to hot summers around here.
>   He was used to her constant complaints.

When the object is a clause, the clause's verb takes the *-ing* form. Its subject is deleted if it is the same as that of *be used to*, as in your example; otherwise, the subject may be cast in either object case (which puts somewhat more focus on the subject as agent of the action) or possessive case (which puts somewhat more focus on the action itself, and gives the verb a 'nounier' quality).

> We're used to him raising objections at every opportunity.
>   We're used to his raising objections at every opportunity.

*BE used to* is quite distinct from the sorta modal *used to*, expressing past habit (the present form is no longer used in this sense). In that idiom the *to* is an 'infinitive marker', followed by a verb in the  infinitive; the subject is always the same as that of *used* and is always omitted

> Back in the 80s I used to collaborate with others quite often.